# Can I create a custom configuration qualifier for android?

Tags: android

I know that I can use the android configuration qualifiers for different screen sizes and different orientations. (I am using android 2.2).

But I need to build my app to a very specific tablet with its unique screen size/resolution.

Can I have another configuration qualifier for my specific tablet so whenever one runs my app using that tablet it will get its layout/dimentsions etc from that specific configuration qualifier?

For example: I want to have a directory named "drawable-specialtablet" and "values-specialtablet".

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No from android sdk this is not possible.

If you are making app only for one device then make your layout and put them in layout folder only same for drawables also.

[check here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/uBmkaVUdjPo)